# new-object System.IO.FileStream passing the file name Vs passing the file path

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have this code as part of a script which get  SharePoint on-premises file and save it to local folder:-

```
$file = $spSourceWeb.GetFile($ItemAttachmentURLPrefix + $attachment)
$bytes = $file.OpenBinary() 
$AttachmentFileName = $FilePrefix + "_AP_" + $InvoiceIDFormatted + "_" + $attachment
$Attachmentpath = $AttachmentFolder + $AttachmentFileName
$fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($Attachmentpath, "OpenOrCreate") 
$fs.Write($bytes, 0 , $bytes.Length)    
$fs.Close()
```

now at first i thought the `$Attachmentpath` inside the `$fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($Attachmentpath, "OpenOrCreate")` will define the path where the file will be saved locally, but seems this variable `$Attachmentpath` will define the file name.. so what define the file local path?

Thanks

Comment: Always pass the full path to .NET APIs that require a "path". Otherwise you depend on .NETs current directory, which is a different variable than PowerShell's and they are not automatically synchronized. For more robustness and platform-independence, use `$Attachmentpath = Join-Path $AttachmentFolder $AttachmentFileName`

Comment: @zett42 thanks for the info but i did not get what is the answer for my question? thanks

Comment: `$AttachmentPath` should be full folder path + file name. Assuming `$AttachmentFolder` contains the full folder path (with trailing backslash), you are basically doing it right.